# Google Analytics send two custom dimensions with gtag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

currently on my website i'm trying to send two custom dimensions to Analytics.

One is client_id, the other is environment.
Both are saved the same way: Name, scope: hit and both active. The only differences are the names and index.

In my code I have this:

```
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'GTAG-UA', {
        'custom_map': {
            'dimension1': 'client_id',
            'dimension2': 'environment'
        }
    });

    gtag('event', 'analytics', {'client_id': env.client_id, 'environment': env.baseurl});
```

The thing is, when i'm doing a custom report with custom dimension as client_id, everything is fine, I have the datas, but when i'm doing one with environment, no data, like if nothing was sent.

I checked the env.baseurl and it's correct, it's set.
The only difference between client_id and environment is that client_id is an int, while environment is a url (so a string).

Is there any restriction on strings or maybe on URLs ?
Or maybe there's something wrong in my code ?

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential issues to rule out.

1) Is the data being sent to GA?  You can verify this by looking at the network request tab and looking for the event going to https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect and check out the parameters it is sending. Here is a simple translation:

```
ec: Event Category
ea: Event Action <---- You should see this one based on your example
el: Event Label
cd1: client_id
cd2: environment
```

If you see cd1 and cd2 being populated, then most likely the data is being sent properly.

2) Are you looking in the right place for this data?  If it's being sent to GA, have you defined what the custom dimension is in the admin section of GA?

3) Maybe environment is a protected name? It wouldn't be the craziest guess.